# HTML: Button that cancels required input and redirects back to index

Tags: html, forms, validation, submit, required

I'm working on a project where users are asked to sign up for an account. I'm currently trying to figure out how to get a button to both cancel a current form and redirect back to an index page.

The user is directed to a simple page where they can enter their name. The name is currently "required", so a user must enter it in if they want to create an account. 
The user has two options on this page:
1. enter in name, click "Create Account"
2. click "Cancel Create Account"

Right now, whenever I click on "Cancel Create Account", I kept getting a message telling me to fill in the "Name" field since it's required. How can I bypass this so I can just return to the index page and not submit the form?

I've already tried "formnovalidate" and that hasn't worked. I've been searching for some other solutions but none that does both a redirect and a cancel.

Here's a CodePen for this project: https://codepen.io/anfperez/pen/oRgoOm

```
<label>Name</label>
<input id="name" name="name" maxlength="80" required/>

<input id="register" type="submit" name="submit" value="CREATE ACCOUNT" /> 
<!--this is supposed to redirect back to an index page -->
<a href="./"><button style="margin-left:20px;" noformvalidation>CANCEL CREATE ACCOUNT</button></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a link, use a link.

If you want a submit button, use a submit button.

Don't use both for the same control. It isn't allowed in HTML anyway.